# auto-delete a record when the expiry date passes

Tags: php, mysql

so basically, my site displays a list of jobs to the user including its details, dates and expiry date. now the user can delete the job, what i want to add is auto deletion. so the job should delete itself after the expiry date passes, im unsure of the best way to go about it.

this is the code that brings the jobs out of the database to display, aswell as a delete statement, which allows the user the manually delete a job based on what they select.

```
function getJobs($conn)
{

 //$query = "SELECT * FROM jobs";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM job WHERE user_ID = :user_ID"; 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    //$stmt->bindValue(':user_ID', $_SESSION["user_ID"]);
    $stmt->bindValue(':user_ID', $_SESSION['user_ID']);
    $stmt->execute();

    $workers=array();
    while($worker=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
        $workers[]=$worker;
    }
    return $workers;
}

//INNER JOIN driver ON jobs.user_ID = driver.user_ID



function getAllJobs($conn)
{
 //$query = "SELECT * FROM jobs";
 $query = "SELECT * FROM job WHERE admin_id = :admin_id";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':admin_id', $_SESSION['user_ID']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $workers=array();
    while($worker=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
        $workers[]=$worker;
    }
    return $workers;
}
```

Comment: i saw that response, but the answers werent really clear enough. is this not possible with a simple DELETE statement

Comment: You can delete the expired records with a delete statement yes, but you will need some cron-job in order to run that statement automatically on a time basis.

Comment: @RichardMarks you can set cronjob for this. it will helps you. like run cronjob every 5 minute bases. which deletes past jobs.